# ¿Por qué se necesita el subjuntivo en esta traducción? «No tiene sentido pedir tortilla (...) solo porque *estemos* en España»

Tags: gramática, subjuntivo, tiempos-verbales

En un artículo reciente ([*¿Por qué las tortillas de patata de los bares son tan malas?*](https://elcomidista.elpais.com/elcomidista/2018/06/20/articulo/1529516558_012009.html)), un crítico gastronómico de El País hace referencia a un fragmento del libro *Hotel Nirvana*, de Manuel Leguineche (*La vuelta a Europa por los hoteles míticos y sus historias*):

> Hotel Ritz de Madrid. Salón de la Suite Real. Woody Allen y su mujer, Soon Yi, en albornoz. Allen lucha con una tortilla de patata: «No tiene sentido —le riñe a su joven esposa— que hayas pedido tortilla española solo porque **estemos** en España, es un completo error. Parece de plomo. Está como vulcanizada. Es como comer una piedra.»

Estoy confundido por el uso del subjuntivo en este caso.  El visitante ya estaba en España, por lo que no hay duda o deseo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El subjuntivo también tiene el tiempo sinónimo del condicional.  Es decir, 
estaríamos = estemos.

Generalmente, cuando la condición se expresa en la cláusula dependiente, se usa el subjuntivo en lugar del condicional.  Por eso vemos el subjuntivo aquí.

En este caso, se usa el subjuntivo como condicional.  Considerando la condición que estemos en España, comemos buena tortilla.

Es decir, en una forma más sencilla, por el caso de que estemos en España, comemos buena tortilla.

Comment: Bien. ¿Te animas a expandir un poco la respuesta para hacerla más genérica y útil para futuros lectores?

Comment: Gracias @fedorqui. Yo no quería poner el sombrero de gramaticalista, pero ahí está. Espero que lo expliqué bien. Ya han pasado varios años que enseño el castellano.

Comment: Me gusta tu respuesta.  Preferiría "Considerando la posibilidad que estemos en España."  Allen está tratando su estancia en España como una premisa.  Para los fines de su **si p entonces q** (que según él no es una inferencia válida), tiene que tratar la como algo tentativo, que no se ha demostrado todavía.

Answer (score 2):

La conjunción *[porque](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ThtjSks)* tiene dos valores:

> 1. conj. causal. Por causa o razón de que. *No pudo asistir porque estaba ausente. Porque es rico no quiere estudiar.*
> 2. conj. final. para que. *Recemos porque no llueva.*

Curiosamente, fíjate que los ejemplos del primer caso llevan el verbo en indicativo. En la frase que muestras bien se podría haber escrito lo siguiente:

> No tiene sentido que pidas tortilla, porque estamos en España.

Sin embargo fíjate que esta frase no implica lo mismo que la original. Esta frase parece indicar que todo el mundo sabe, que es un hecho, que en España no se puede pedir tortilla. La frase original introduce un elemento subjetivo, de opinión del que habla, que es por lo que se usa el subjuntivo, así:

> No tiene sentido que pidas tortilla solo porque estemos en España.

La opinión parece en este caso ir en contra de lo que todo el mundo sabe: que en España debería ser lógico pedir tortilla española. El subjuntivo refuerza ese aspecto de opinión.

Comment: Vaya, habría jurado que el "porque" de la segunda se escribe separado.

Comment: @FGSUZ de hecho la RAE avisa que se puede escribir separado en esa segunda acepción.

Comment: Curioso lo de "porque" junto, aunque lo diga la RAE. Ahora bien, @Charlie, no me parece que "porque" tenga sentido de finalidad en la oración en cuestión. Para mí, es claramente causal: *No tiene sentido que hayas pedido tortilla española **por el solo hecho de que** estemos en España*.

Answer (score 2):

En estos casos, lo mejor es comparar el subjuntivo con el indicativo.

Mi impresión es que el segundo subjuntivo simplemente tiene una razón de ser sintáctica: su uso garantiza que la segunda subordinada dependa de la primera y no de la proposición principal. A mi entender, el primer subjuntivo arrastra el segundo. Veamos:

> No tiene sentido que hayas pedido tortilla española solo porque estemos en España: (el hecho de) que hayas pedido tortilla española solo porque estemos en España no tiene sentido.

Si usamos indicativo, la oración se vuelve ambigua y la segunda subordinada puede depender de la proposición principal "no tiene sentido". La ambigüedad es mayor si se elimina el adverbio "solo":

> No tiene sentido que hayas pedido tortilla española porque **estamos** en España.

Aunque sería un contrasentido, imaginemos por un momento que en España no se cocina tortilla española. El uso del indicativo podría volver la segunda subordinada dependiente de la principal y no de la primera subordinada:

> Como/Puesto que **estamos** en España, no tiene sentido que hayas pedido tortilla española.

Mi hipótesis es que el segundo subjuntivo vuelve la segunda subordinada indiscutiblemente dependiente de la primera subordinada y no permite ninguna ambigüedad. Imaginemos un caso donde no se dé el absurdo de que la tortilla española no sea típica de España:

```
No tiene sentido que estés llorando porque estemos lejos.
```

(En este caso es claro que la persona está llorando porque está lejos.)

```
No tiene sentido que estés llorando porque estamos lejos.
```

(Esta oración es ambigua: puede significar lo mismo que la anterior, o bien que, al estar lejos, no tiene sentido el llanto.)

Answer (score 1):

Es una buena pregunta. El subjuntivo no solamente se usa para "duda" o "deseo", sino, en general, para cualquier cosa que **no es un hecho** (hablando rápido; hay más sutilezas).

Ahora bien, es lógico pensar que ahí debería ir un indicativo, porque efectivamente "estáis" en España, y eso es un hecho.

Pero el lenguaje no se preocupa de la realidad. Por eso podemos mentir.
La gramática se refiere a la oración, aunque la oración no se corresponda con la realidad.

En tu caso, está **abstrayéndose** del lugar. Nos olvidamos de que estamos en España. Nuestra frase es en general:

> En caso de que estemos en España, debes pedir tortilla.

O bien la negación: puedes pedir otra cosa.

Pero observa que el hablante se está refiriendo a una situación hipotética, general. Es un condicional. Si estás en España, puedes no pedirla.

Ocurre que se cumple la condición: sí estáis en España.
Pero esa es una frase general.

Se ve mejor "reescribiéndola así":

> El hecho de que estemos en España no significa que debas pedir tortilla.

Es una oración condicional, que rige subjuntivo.